# How include file file.php in another file.php

Tags: php

Suppose to have two file, `home1.php` and `home2.php` in different folders. 
This is folder disposition:

```
root
  folder1
    home1.php
  folder2
    home2.php
```

I need to include `home1.php` in `home2.php` so in home2.php I do:

```
<?php include('../folder1/home1.php'); ?>
```

But it give me `file not found`.Anyone can help me?

Comment: If that's `HTTP 404 File Not Found` that has nothing to do with the `include`

Comment: Are you geting a 404 error, or a php exception?

Comment: failed to open stream: File o directory doesn't exists. But file exists!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try debugging by echoing $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'folder1/home1.php'?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php include(dirname(__FILE__)."/../folder1/home1.php"); ?>
```